# Transforming dataframe by making column using unique row values python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe

```
Name      Activities
Eric      Soccer,Baseball,Swimming
Natasha   Soccer
Mike      Basketball,Baseball
```

I need to transform it into following dataframe

```
Activities     Name
Soccer          Eric,Natasha,Mike
Swimming        Eric
Baseball        Eric,Mike
Basketball      Mike
```

how should I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Mike does not have Soccer as an activity, but you have Mike listed in the Soccer output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `pd.get_dummies`

First, use `get_dummies`:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Name').Activities.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

Now using `stack` and `agg`:

```
tmp.mask(tmp.eq(0)).stack().reset_index('Name').groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

```
                     Name
Baseball       Eric, Mike
Basketball           Mike
Soccer      Eric, Natasha
Swimming             Eric
```

---

#### Using `str.split` and `melt`

```
(df.set_index('Name').Activities.str.split(',', expand=True)
    .reset_index().melt(id_vars='Name').groupby('value').Name.agg(', '.join))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the Activities by performing a `split` and then converting the resulting list to a `Series`.
Then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) from wide to long format, and `groupby` the resulting `value` column (which is `Activities`).
In your grouped data frame, `join` the Name fields associated with each Activity.

Like this:

```
(df.Activities.str.split(",")
   .apply(pd.Series)
   .merge(df, right_index=True, left_index=True)
   .melt(id_vars="Name", value_vars=[0,1,2])
   .groupby("value")
   .agg({'Name': lambda x: ','.join(x)})
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={"value":"Activities"})
)
```

Output:

```
   Activities          Name
0    Baseball     Eric,Mike
1  Basketball          Mike
2      Soccer  Eric,Natasha
3    Swimming          Eric
```

Note: The `reset_index()` and `rename()` methods at the end of the chain are just cosmetic; the main operations are complete after the `groupby` aggregation.